# MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest

I have this method to retrieve data from my database :

```
@GetMapping(path="/login/in", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
User loginA(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLogin)
{
    logger.debug(newLogin);
    return repository.findByEmailAddress(newLogin.getEMail()).get(0).getUser();
}
```

And I'm trying to use this method like this :

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url='http://localhost:8080/login/in';
    let data=JSON.stringify({ email:this.state.email,passwordHash:this.state.passwordHash});
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(data);
```

It gives me error - *400*

And Spring says :

---

*Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: com.mua.cse616.Model.User com.mua.cse616.Controller.LoginCredentialController.loginA(com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential)]*

**How to resolve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you're using `@GetMapping` and sending body `@RequestBody LoginCredential newLogin` at the same time. You should user `@RequestBody` with `@PostMapping` or `@PutMapping` but not `@Getmapping`.

So, try to change your request to POST. That would solve the exception.

```
@PostMapping(path="/login/in", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
User loginA(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLogin)
{
    logger.debug(newLogin);
    return repository.findByEmailAddress(newLogin.getEMail()).get(0).getUser();
}
```

---

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url='http://localhost:8080/login/in';
    let data=JSON.stringify({ email:this.state.email,passwordHash:this.state.passwordHash});
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(data);
```